# Word for Mac license

Tags: ms-office, license

Have MacBook Pro 2010 running Mavericks. Hard drive crashed/replaced at Apple Store Minneapolis in June. Now cannot access Word for Mac. 3 choices: 1) enter product key 2) sign in to existing Office 365 subscription 3) try Office 365.

Left Minneapolis for Wyoming for a month before trying to access Word, old info not available here if I had it. Original e-mail address & password long forgotten. New problem for me, lost.

Comment: Did you/Apple use Migration Assistant with a Time Machine backup disk to restore your HD?

Comment: In the future save you MS product key in the key chain, or maybe it is there?

Comment: How did you _originally_ acquire Word for Mac?